# oracle sql trigger to prevent insertion of record

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, triggers, ddl

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger million_trigger
BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE on employee
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.SALARY>1000000)
BEGIN
if inserting then       
    RETURN ;    
end if;

if updating then 
    RETURN ;
end if;
end;
/

BEGIN
    PKG_insertrec.insertrec(121,'Mark',2000000);
END;
/
```

Hello all , I wrote a trigger to prevent the insertion of a record if the SALARY is above 1,000,000. I have already written a stored procedure insertrec which is in a package PKG_insertrec. The problem is that the trigger does not work even though the trigger was successfully compiled.

Comment: Why, it works. It just does nothing ;)

Comment: i do not want the stored procedure to execute the insert statement

Answer (score 6):

IMHO, your approach is wrong - you don't need triggers for such a simple input validation - just used constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD CONSTRAINT employee_salary CHECK (salary <= 1000000);
```

If you really want to use a trigger, you should `raise` instead of `return` when an invalid input is given.